# Firing events between an iframe and its parent using YUI

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, yui3

I have an iFrame that is firing an event that I want the parent page to pick up. Essentially [the inverse of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998286/how-to-get-iframe-to-listen-to-same-events-as-parent-and-fire-the-same-handlers). I can pick up the event inside the iFrame, so I know it's firing, but nothing happens in the parent.

I'm using YUI 3 so any answers based around this get a double-thumbs up, but all help is gratefully received.

Comment: Desperately seeking: an answer to this exact question. Did you make any headway? I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601325/trigger-events-in-iframes-parent-window

Answer (score 4):

Apparently events don't propagate across frames.  Here's how I'm working around it:

In the parent frame define this global function:

```
var fireGlobalEvent = function (e, param) {
  YUI().use('event-custom', function (Y) {
    var publisher = new Y.EventTarget();
    publisher.publish(e, {
      broadcast:  2,   // global notification
      emitFacade: true // emit a facade so we get the event target
    }).fire(param);
  });
};
```

Then just call this in the child to trigger the event in the parent.

```
window.parent.fireGlobalEvent('my_custom_global_event', 'an_extra_param');
```

Then the event is caught by parent modules with:

```
    Y.Global.on('my_custom_global_event', function (e, param) {
       // do something
    });
```