# (yet another) access iframe js function from parent - Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, iframe, flowplayer

I know it has been discussed a lot a times but I can't find a way to make this work :

I launch flowplayer (iframe) through a modal window. When the modal is closed, the sound of the video can still be heard.

This modal has an onclose event. The iframe is on the same domain as the parent.

The player is launched with this code :

player = $f("player", "flowplayer.swf").ipad();

It is launched via a variable because at the time I did this it was the only solution to make the .ipad() work.

Whatever I write in the close function , (the flowplayer doc says $f().stop(); but it's the same with player.stop(); ) I get "$f() is not defined" or message telling the player is not defined.

I really don't know what to do, some help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things.

1. The code that will turn off the iFrame needs to live inside that iFrame. If you try to execute $f() from your main page it likely doesn't exist.
2. On your parent page you call the code from within the iFrame and call a function that stops the audio.

[Trigger events in iframe's parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601325/trigger-events-in-iframes-parent-window)

This is close to what you need.

Comment: Ok thanks very much that was kind of it, here is what I've done : 
**In parent** :
`function onIframeClose() {
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.anotherFunction();
}`
**In iframe** 
`function anotherfunction() {
$f().stop();
}`
Not sure if this second function is the best way to do but at least it works. Thanks !